# How to make an HTML element stay on multiple html pages

Tags: html, html5-audio, browser-refresh

I have a web-page - an online comic: prophetsangel.net and I have an html player which plays music. The purpose of this player is to add additional atmospheric content to the comic. Now each individual comic page has its own html page: slide00001.html slide00002.html slide00003.html slide00004.html etc.

I am currently using a pre-developed service which displays a music player on every single page. without refreshing it. Here is where you can find its code: http://scmplayer.net/

Now I want to switch to using a standard HTML5  tag to play my sounds but I want to specify which html pages a specific player will be displayed on.

For instance I want the player 1 to be displayed on slide00001.html slide00002.html and slide00003.html but I want player 2 with completely different music to be displayed on slide00004.html and slide00005.html

I require a constant display so that when the user goes from slide00001.html to slide00002.html one wouldn't have to restart the player music.

Perhaps there is a code which I would put in the html page I want the player to start playing - eg. I want the player one to start playing in slide00002.html, I insert the code in the head or body section and it specifies "keep player open for slide00003.html, slide00004.html slide00005.html". Now when It reaches slide00006.html, the orevious code will no longer be active and I will specify the same code but with different music and different tracking pages "keep player open for slide00007.html, slide00008.html slide00009.html"

Just thought this might help to get the message right.

Comment: Why don't you just create a single player for the common slides, and a separate player for when the track changes (on a new page).  Just set autoplay to `true` on the `Configure Setting` tab on http://scmplayer.net/

Comment: Yes but as I mentioned in the post, I dont want to use smc player

Answer (score 1):

You should consider making your entire site a single html page and use [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), [Moustache.js](http://mustache.github.com/) or a similar technology to route your users to different partials (small HTML fragments that can be created/deleted in javascript) without actually navigating to another page.  This way parts of your site could change without refreshing everything.

I actually did this for my Web Comic viewer (work in progress): http://ucfpawn.dyndns.info/WebComicService/new.html#/login